# Transform scale - I want it to overflow but it doesnt

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, sass

Im working on my carousel and ill try to explaind as much as possible of what im trying to achieve with the specifyc code below. What im trying to do is when you hover the image im applying transform: scale(1.2)

It does work but the image doesn't overflow and is being hidden from the div's . I do try to play around with `overflow-x: hidden & overflow-y: visible` but it still doesnt work. I dont wanna work over it for now with position and then to fetch the positioning of them throught window object and then apply it cuz I think It can be done much simplier. I found a related issue but its not a carousel.

SCSS FILE

```
@mixin ArrowStyle {
      width: 2rem;
      height: 2rem;
      color: white;
    }
    
    @mixin btnStyle {
      width: 3rem;
      height: 100%;
      display: grid;
      place-items: center;
      background: rgba(57, 21, 21, 1);
      border-radius: 15px;
      cursor: pointer;
      justify-self: baseline;
      &:hover {
        background: #b92f2c;
      }
    }
    
    .carouseldiv {
      margin: 5rem auto;
      width: 80%;
      display: grid;
      place-items: center;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 10fr 1fr;
    }
    
    .carouselbtnleft {
      @include btnStyle();
      justify-self: baseline;
    }
    .carouselbtnright {
      @include btnStyle();
      justify-self: end;
    }
    .leftbutton {
      @include ArrowStyle;
    }
    
    .rightbutton {
      @include ArrowStyle;
    }
    .viewport {
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .carousel {
      width: 100%;
      height: 20rem;
      display: flex;
      gap: 2rem;
    
      transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    }
    
    .img {
      height: 100%;
      width: 15rem;
      object-fit: contain;
      transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
      cursor: pointer;
      &:hover {
        transform: scale(1.2);
      }
    }
```

TSX FILE

```
import { RiArrowRightSLine, RiArrowLeftSLine } from "react-icons/ri";
import Image from "next/image";
import { useCustomCarousel } from "./useCustomCarouel";
import styles from "./styles.module.scss";

const CustomCarousel = () => {
  const { handlers, values } = useCustomCarousel();

  if (!values.twentymovies) {
    return <p>Loading...</p>;
  }
  return (
    <div className={styles.carouseldiv}>
      <div
        className={styles.carouselbtnleft}
        onClick={handlers.LeftArrowHandler}
      >
        <RiArrowLeftSLine className={styles.leftbutton} />
      </div>
      <div className={styles.viewport}>
        <div
          className={styles.carousel}
          ref={values.viewportRef}
          style={{ transform: `translateX(${values.translateX}px)` }}
        >
          {values.twentymovies!.map((movie, index) => {
            return (
              <Image
                key={index}
                width={100}
                height={100}
                className={styles.img}
                src={movie.image[movie.image.length - 1][1]}
                alt={movie.title}
              />
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div
        className={styles.carouselbtnright}
        onClick={handlers.RightArrowHandler}
      >
        <RiArrowRightSLine className={styles.rightbutton} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default CustomCarousel;
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make your code work in a sandbox but I couldn't.
Anyways I think what you need to do here is to move your transform: scale(1.2) to the parent div, the one with the carousel class.
Also be careful with your viewport element, it shouldn't have overflow: hidden.

Just for the sake of it, you don't need to use transform: scale() you can use scale: 1.2 straight away.
[See reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale)

Sorry if my answer seems messy.
If my tips don't work maybe you can provide a codesandbox or something and I'll try to help more precisely.

Comment: What If I pass you the repo? I tryed to replicate it on codesandbox tbh but I gota modify plenty of code from it

Comment: I don't have this kind of time atm I'm sorry. 

Did you try anything from what I suggested?

Comment: Yeah I actually did and It doesnt seem to be the case. Day to day tho i'll host it to github pages and pass it here.

Comment: https://georgenonis.github.io/nonis-movie-seeker/
There you go. No any responsivess btw so far so just check it on 1440 +